# How exactly are standard errors of coefficients (factor levels) computed in a two-way ANOVA?

Tags: standard-error, linear-model, covariance-matrix, anova

In one-way ANOVA ($Y_{ij} = A_i + \epsilon_{ij}$) the standard errors of coefficients are computed pretty easily:

$$SE_{\widehat{A_{i}}} = \sqrt{\text{mean residual sum of squares} \over \text{size of group i}}$$

How exactly are the standard errors of coefficients (factor levels) computed in two-way ANOVA? Is there similar expression? I did some research but no result. I've been trying to find out how is the variance-covariance matrix defined for the linear models (quite a basic thing I thought), but with no result!

**I highly prefer direct expression** like the above with sums and indices over the matrix multiplication stuff. Thanks! :-)

Here is example test code for two-way ANOVA

```
set.seed(2)
y = c(rnorm(200, 20, 4), rnorm(300, 30, 4), rnorm(400, 40, 4), rnorm(500, 50, 4))
cat1 = as.factor(c(rep(1, 200), rep(2, 300), rep(3, 400), rep(4, 500)))
rand_order = sample(1:length(cat1))
cat2 = cat1[rand_order]
cat2y = c(rep(1, 200), rep(-2, 300), rep(3, 400), rep(-4, 500))
y = y + cat2y[rand_order]
summary(lm(y ~ 0 + cat1 + cat2))
```

Comment: Your model is not the standard 2-way ANOVA, but using matrix math, the SEs can be found like in [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29518/1909). The SEs of the coefficient estimates are the diagonal of the matrix $\hat{\sigma} (\bf{X}'\bf{X})^{-1}$,
where $\hat{\sigma}^{2} = ||\bf{e}||^{2} / (N-\text{Rank}(\bf{X}))$ is the estimate of the error variance
($||\bf{e}||^{2}$ is the sum of squared residuals, $\bf{e} = (\bf{I}-\bf{P}) \bf{y}$, $N$ the total number of observations, and $\bf{X}$ is the design matrix, and $\bf{P} = \bf{X} (\bf{X}'\bf{X})^{-1} \bf{X}'$ the hat-matrix).